# get_categories() only returns categories in use

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

```
$args = array(
"type"      => "post",      
"orderby"   => "name",
"order"     => "ASC");

$types = get_categories($args);
```

When this is executed. $types only contains "Uncategorized" since it is used as the default to my posts. There are other categories available, but they are not returned unless I have a post that uses them.
How can I return all possible categories and not just the ones that are in use?

Comment: If you're reading this QA and still are having no luck, you're likely needing to set `hide_empty` to `false` in your `get_categories`' arguments, as per this guide https://wpza.net/get_categories-not-working-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
<?php $args = array("hide_empty" => 0,
                    "type"      => "post",      
                    "orderby"   => "name",
                    "order"     => "ASC" );
      $types = get_categories($args);
?>
```

Comment: @coolguy see [WP_Term_Query::__construct()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/#parameters) for information on valid arguments.